# Click and drag on bootstrap button leads to incorrect highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

After clicking on a bootstrap button, if you drag the mouse away and release it somewhere else, the button will remain highlighted as if you are still hovering over it (not active, just highlighted). Is there any way to unhighlight using javascript or jQuery? The only thing I could think of was to simulate a mouse click somewhere else.

Tested on the bootstrap homepage.

Comment: I don't know why it bothers you, but you can use .blur() of jquery for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it so that there is no select on drag for the button at all by adding this to the selector:

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
```

Or you could specify what color you want the selection to be by adding this:

```
::selection {
  background: #fff;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #fff;
}
```